# Javascript Targeting Child Elements in a ID

Tags: javascript, dom

i'm currently learning javascript and had a question. 
I am trying to target only the h1 tag in the div id=title i tried a few ways using this as a reference site amongst others: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-jsanddom-pr/sidefile1.html

but nothing seems to be working, i get back the value "undefined" 
esentially what i want to do is only target the h1 and change the text to something else.
how do i do that? is this along the right path or is there a different way to do it?

```
<div id="title">
    <h1>Javascript Lesson 1</h1>
    <p>The basics</p>
</div>

<script>
var title = document.getElementById('title');
    var titleHeading = title.firstChild;
    console.log (title.value);
</script>
```

any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `h1` _is not_ the first child of the `div` – the _text node_ containing the whitespace between `<div id="title">` and `<h1>` is. And neither `div` nor `h1` do have a `value` attribute.

Comment: Just a small addition to what CBroe said, Form elements like INPUT(whatever type) and TEXTAREA have a 'value' property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [Element.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName).

```
var titleElement = document.getElementById("title");
var titleChildren = titleElement.getElementsByTagName("H1");

// Do something with children.
// In your example code, you'll only have one element returned
console.log(titleChildren[0].innerHTML);

// To change the text, simply access the innerHTML property
titleChildren[0].innerHTML = "[New Value]"
```

Here's [a working fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/XQL6h/1/).

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the h1 you want to modify will always be the first h1 child you could do something like this:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('title').getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "New Name";
</script>
```

Comment: If you're going to regurgitate someone else's code, you should improve upon it with greater explanation, documentation, etc. The same answer with less explanation is just noise.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, but if you didn't notice, our answers were posted 6 minutes apart and you edited yours 6 minutes after mine. I didn't copy yours or regurgitate or whatever you think. On my end (again didn't refresh before clicking submit) there were still no answers.

Answer (score 0):

The first child of the `<div>` (in your example) is a text node. Text nodes don't have a `value` property. Even if you remove the whitespace between the `<div>` and the `<h1>` to make it the first child node, the `<h1>` still doesn't have a `value` property. What it does have is a child text node with the node value "Javascript Lesson 1".

What you want is to retrieve a reference to that text node, and its value. There are different ways to do this. For instance:

```
<div id="title">
  <h1>Javascript Lesson 1</h1> <!-- White space before <h1> -->
  <p>The basics</p>
</div>

<script>
  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  var titleHeading = title.childNodes[1];
  console.log (titleHeading.firstChild.nodeValue);
</script>
```

or:

```
<div id="title"
 ><h1>Javascript Lesson 1</h1> <!-- No white space -->
  <p>The basics</p>
</div>

<script>
  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  var titleHeading = title.firstChild;
  console.log (titleHeading.firstChild);
</script>
```

or:

```
<div id="title">
  <h1>Javascript Lesson 1</h1>
  <p>The basics</p>
</div>

<script>
  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  var titleHeading = title.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
  console.log (titleHeading.innerHTML);
</script>
```

or some permutation of the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a collection of children back with `Document.querySelectorAll()`. Here are two examples:

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("iframe[data-src]");
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("div.note, div.alert");
```

As you can see, it is nearly JQuery like. Notice the comma in the second example. JQuery would use a space there. These examples were taken from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#examples).

If you don't want a collection, (if you want a single element) `document.querySelector("#myCSSSelector");` is what you want.